# terra::project seems to be changing the values of a raster

Tags: raster, r, terra

I am trying to calculate the proportion of a land use category in R just like it's explained here: [Calculating continuous raster representing land cover proportion from categorical raster using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297788/calculating-continuous-raster-representing-land-cover-proportion-from-categorica)

My original raster has these characteristics:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 17237, 33337, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 142302.1, 975727.1, 6027307, 6458232  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) 
source      : lu_1990_CopyRaster21.tif 
categories  : NAME 
name        :          NAME 
min value   : 11_Settlement 
max value   :        20_Sea
```

I am using a for loop to iterate over each land use category and then I use the following code to calculate the % of each land use category in the coarser raster (now 100 m resolution) and then project to get a raster with longitude/latitude coordinates. Lastly I transform from SpatRaster to RasterLayer (as required by the next operations).

```
bool_i <- lu90[[i-10]] == 1 # The values in this raster are NA, FALSE, TRUE
aggr <- aggregate(bool_i, fact = 4, fun = mean) # The values in this raster are 0, 1/16, 2/16, ..., 1
aggr <- project(aggr, "EPSG:4326") # Now the values have changed. I get over 99999 unique values
```

One of the final rasters:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2755, 9516, 26216580  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.001485882, 0.001485882  (x, y)
extent     : 2.923104, 17.06276, 54.17155, 58.26516  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : reg_lulc_newbasemap_present_pixel_2022_2022_Settlement 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

Why are the values changing after doing `aggr <- project(aggr, "EPSG:4326")`? How can I fix this?

Comment: That's because when you reproject raster from one CRS to another, it's dimmensions (cell width/height) changes as well; you may notice `nrow`, `ncol` and `resolution` on input and output rasters. If cell dimension (and placement) changes, the value in cell changes as well.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of terra::project(). There is a method argument that should be set to "near" if dealing with categorical layers. Not sure why you think you have to convert to a RasterLayer, but that is another question I guess.

Comment: Thank you darius.goergen, this solved the issue.